# Unrecognized Escape Sequence C# 6 String Interpolation

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

According to [New Features in C# 6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx), you should be able to declare strings as such:

```
var name = "world";
WriteLine("hello, \{name}");
```

For the output:

> hello, world

I have created a new Console application, set the Target Framework to **.NET Framework 4.6**, and I am getting the error *"Unrecognized Escape Sequence"*

I am using `Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 CTP Version 14.0.22512.0 DP`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The string interpolation convention changed. It is now using the "$" operator:

```
var name = "world";
WriteLine($"hello, {name}");
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, that worked.  I read they had thoughts of changing it, but couldn't find any documentation on that.  Do you happen to have a reference for this?

Comment: Yes, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx)